# PayPal Payflow Pro (Legacy) Implementation

Tags: php, paypal, legacy-code, payflowpro

Is there anyone that has successfully **implement Payflow Pro in PHP**?

A client has forced me to use the Payflow Pro (Legacy) on the website, and it seems PayPal has removed the documentations for it. [Link here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow-pro/)

I only need the documentation of how this service works.

*Note: I can't use the **hosted checkout page** or anything new like express checkout(this needs a PayPal Business account, not Payflow)

[image]

Thanks before

Comment: Please tell your client that there is no point implementing a legacy interface because such interfaces are almost certainly living on borrowed time as it is, and if PayPal chooses to remove it then you'll just have to do the work all over again to implement one of their current interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PHP sdk for payflow pro, but you will lot of materials on internet on how to post data to payflow from PHP.

On you concern about Hosted page, please check payflowlink on the guide. For this you don't need a Paypal account.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Payflow information here.

[Payflow Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow-gateway/)